# selenium java drag and drop - trying to drag and drop

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to drag draggable 1 to drop here box. Draggable 1 can get clicked and holding, but not be able to drag to the drop box. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");

    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"todrag\"]/span[" + n + "]"));
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@dropzone]"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775864/click-and-drag-selenium-chrome-webdriver-is-not-dragging-but-will-click-and-h/48781939#48781939) will help you

Comment: Hi @Workhard
you got the solution for this question / problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try Action Dragged and dropped method to achieve above functionality. Also your xpaths are incorrect. please refer correct xpath as below:

```
  //span[contains(text(),'Draggable'"+ n +"')] 
  //div[@id='mydropzone']
```

**Drag and drop**

```
Actions act=new Actions(driver);                    
act.dragAndDrop(From, To).build().perform()
```

Comment: well. still not working... :(. The draggable 1 is clicked and holding with yellow color, but not moving.